# How do i change time on xasis on live chart with highcharts?

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

how do I set the time on the axis and tooltip with the time in the database?

this is my dataPLLive.php

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/json");

$servername = "....";
$username = ".....";
$password = ".....";
$dbname = "...."

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$query = mysqli_query($conn,   ("SELECT a.`JAM`, AVG(a.PacketLoss) AVG
                                FROM (
                                SELECT  `JAM`,`RNC`,`IPPATH_PM` AS PHB,`VS_IPPM_FORWORD_DROPMEANS` AS PacketLoss, `VSIPPMRttMeans` AS Latency, 'IPPM'
                                FROM `rnc_ippm_meas`
                                WHERE `JAM`>= CURDATE() AND `IPPATH_PM` LIKE '%AF31%'
                                UNION
                                SELECT `JAM`,`RNC`,`IPPOOL_PM`,`VSIPPOOLIPPMForwardDrop-Means`,`VSIPPOOLIPPMRttMeans`, 'IPPOOLPM'
                                FROM `rnc_ippool_ippm_meas` 
                                WHERE `JAM`>= CURDATE() AND `IPPOOL_PM` LIKE '%AF31%') a
                                GROUP BY a.`JAM`
                                LIMIT 10000"));

if (!$query) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
}
$arr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {   

    $value = $row['AVG'];
    $x = strtotime($row['JAM']) * 1000;
    $y = floatval($value);

    $arr[] = array($x, $y);

}
echo json_encode($arr);  
?>
```

heres the output [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLcG4.png),Big thanks if someone can solve this , Thanks

Comment: why you did this `$x = strtotime($row['JAM']) * 1000;`? any purpose?Also change `while` code like this:- `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $arr[] = array( ( strtotime($row['JAM']) * 1000 ), floatval( $row['AVG'] ) );
}`, no need of multiple variable creation and then assign them to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        format: '{value:%H:%M:%S}'
    }
}
```

and

```
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vxron23a/)

Regarding the discrepancy between the database time and the chart time, that might have to do with timezone settings in you DB. These Highchart options might help:

```
time: {
    timezoneOffset: 5 * 60, // Positive value moves time back
    useUTC : false
}
```

Comment: its work sir @Hugs, but time on x still different from my database , here the image [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/GwmnsYl.png) idk what i miss

Comment: @LutfiMiftahudin, will the `time` options help you?

Comment: its not changesir , the time still not same with database , but i think its from dataPLLive.php code `$x = strtotime($row['JAM']) * 1000;` when i change the the value its change the time, but its hard to know how to change the value until its same from database. anyway thanks you so much sir